# Solving $\sin \theta = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ within $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sin \theta = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

My answer for this was $240^°$ and $300^°$ but i'm not sure if that's right or not.

Comment: The sine function is negative in the third and fourth quadrants, so the solution angles should be in the interval $ \ 180º \ < \ \theta \ < \ 360º \ . $  Evaluating $ \ \sin 240º \ $ and $ \ \sin 300º \ $ give the value on the right-hand side of the equation.  So you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it.  [For example, this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20300)  What is your worry?

Comment: Well...When it comes to Math, I often second guess myself.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1^2$$
$$r^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) = r^2(1^2)$$
$$(r\cos\theta)^2 + (r\sin\theta)^2 = r^2$$

$$x^2+y^2 = r^2$$

Draw a circle of radius 2. For what values of $\theta$ would the y-coordinate of the circle $x^2+y^2=2^2$ intersect the line $y = -\sqrt{3}$?

[image]

Hint #2

What does $x$ equal? What is the distance between $(-x, -\sqrt{3})$ and $(x,-\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: I think you mean $y = -\sqrt{3}$? Also, while some extent this explains the intuition behind $\sin$ and $\cos$, I don't see how this actually helps OP solve the problem.

Comment: @Michael T - thank you for your comment. Yes of course, it should be $y = -\sqrt{3}$. Your second comment is also valid, I should have suggested a line of reasoning where the origin, the intersection of the circle with said line, and the projection of the intersection onto the x-axis form the vertices of half of an isosceles triangle.

Comment: it is more helpful to draw the diagram than to think about drawing the diagram.